# Pagination in ADF Data flow

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory, dataflowtask

I have REST API and need to import the data into a Azure SQL Server table.

I am using Data flow because requirement is to flatten the data.

Because the API produces lot of data I want import data in batches.

Pagination rules are different for Copy activity and Data flow, Copy activity QueryParamters with Range is what I need for Data flow.

I would like to implement below in dynamic way, can you please let me know, how I can get the pagination working.

```
abc?$expand=xx,yy,zz&$top=400&$skip=0

abc?$expand=xx,yy,zz&$top=400&$skip=400
```

Example API data: https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$expand=Trips

Comment: Nothing to do with SQL Server so have untagged.

Answer (score 0):

In Mapping data flow **Range pagination is not supported of Rest API**.

1. Using the **Filter activity** we can generate all numbers in our range using `range()` function and then the Filter condition with `mod` to get numbers divisible by 400, ie

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Items | @range(1,44000) |
| Condition | @equals(mod(item(),400),0) |

You will get the array with required numbers to be set for offset.

[image]
2. Now pass this array to foreach activity as below
[image]
3. Create parameter with type string in source Rest DataSource.
[image]

4. Pass that parameter as Dynamic value in relative URL. your values are as follows:

```
base Url: https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(5omxqz45cvuywr5trycvc53q))/People
realtive Url: @dataset().skipvalue
```

[image]

5. After this give source parameter  value as  `?$expand=Trips&$top=3&$skip=@{item()}`  to give the pagination to URL.

[image]

**OUTPUT:**
[image]